# Need a new class when creating a normalized table?

Tags: php, oop, normalization

I have an application that has only two tables: products and type - where each product can have multiple types as attributes. I decided to normalize the database and created another table where I intend to keep the relations between the products and types.

(Disclaimer: I'm relatively new to object oriented programming). I have a class for products, and a class for types. I have been told that I should have a class for every table that I have in the database. Does this also apply to a table created for normalization purposes? If so - what is the best way of dealing with this - should I somehow call both other classes in this third class, or keep it an independent class, and just manage the exchange of information through actual forms on the webpage, etc?

Comment: I'd suggest an ORM to handle this.. or even a framework, like Laravel 4

Comment: thanks, and I plan to probably use a framework in the future, but right now I'm using this project to learn some fundamentals, and trying to increase my programming chops.

Answer (score 1):

If your product_types table only holds foreign keys there is no need to map it to its own class.  Since this is defining a many to many relationship between the tables you can just provide a method in your product class to get the types.

```
getTypes() {
    // retrieve the types for this product and return
}
```

Then add the opposite method in the types object to get the products.

```
getProducts() {
    // retrieve the products for this type and return
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have been told that I should have a class for every table that I have in the database. Does this also apply to a table created for normalization purposes?

Usually when you're designing a database, the first thing you need to do is create a *conceptual data model*. This will allow you do define your entities as well as defining relationships between them. Then you create a *logical data model* to characterize and refine your entities. The last step is the physical data model, which is the closest model there is to a database. Now in this model your entites are now tables, and some of them may or may not relate to your application domain.

For example you could have a travel agency application, where you'd have tables for destinations, flight companies etc... These would map directly to your application because they represent concrete classes. On the other hand you'd also have configurations, sparse data (billing...) or associative tables (like you have here). They don't map to your current application. This concept is called *impedance mismatch*. See this diagram I found online :

[image: impedance mismatch]

Finally to answer your question : no you don't need to map it to a class, because it has nothing to do in the application domain. Of course you still need to handle it some way (using DAO and SQL basically). You could also use an ORM, like suggested in the comments by @RobW, which can abstract and map directly your database.